# Identifying the Memory Leak whether in NSMutableArray or UIAlertViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got my app crash and identified its due to memory leak through Instruments. The memory leak said **Leaked Object** as `NSMutableArray`. However it also says **ResponsibleFrame** as `UIAlertViewController`. I thought as I used `UIAlertView` instead of `UIAlertViewController` its showing Responsibleframe as `UIAlertViewController` and modified `UIAlertView` to `UIAlertViewController`. Still it shows the same memory leak. How I am suppose to resolve this.
[image: Memory Leak Image]

**Updated Code**

```
// ModelClass.h
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *productListArray;
-(void) getProductInfoWs:(WebService *) webServiceReference :(GlobalValues *) valueReference :(NSString *) categoryId :(UIView *) overlayView;

//  ModelClass.m

-(void) getProductInfoWs:(WebService *) webServiceReference :(GlobalValues *) valueReference :(NSString *) categoryId :(UIView *) overlayView{
productListArray=[localstoreModel getProductInfo:1];
if([[ResponseData objectForKey:@"status"] boolValue]==1){
   productListArray=[[ResponseData objectForKey:@"result"][@"category_products"] mutableCopy];
} 
else{
if([httpResponse statusCode]==200 && [[ResponseData objectForKey:@"status"] boolValue]==0){
[webServiceReference AlertMessage:[ResponseData objectForKey:@"errormsg"]];
}
else{
  [webServiceReference AlertMessage:@"2"];
}
}

//CustomAlert.m
-(void) AlertMessage:(NSString *) message{
UIAlertView *alertBox = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"Information!")
                                           message:message
                                           delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:LocalizedString(@"OK")
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertBox show];
}
```

**Added Image**
[image: Reference Count Image]

Comment: You should show the code you think is responsible for the leak.

Comment: @I'L'I Updated the code. Could you please check it?

Comment: Have you tried using `NSAutoreleasePool`?

Comment: I am using ARC, still tried with `@autoreleasepool {...}` and getting the same issue.

Comment: Post the code which you tried to wrap with `@autoreleasepool { ... }`.

Comment: @I'L'I I came across the release count where the count is +1, which is not released in `UIAlertController`. See the updated Image, Will this says something to resolve?

Comment: You're worried about leaking _48 bytes_?????

Comment: @matt No, The app crashes when the leakage occurs.

Comment: Then the problem is not the leak and you need to ask about the crash instead. A leak does not cause a crash! Rethink the entire way you're asking this question. Tell us what we need to know in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ARC but your productListArray has an retain qualifier, replace it with a strong qualifier or a weak qualifier (if this array is already owned by another object)